# Compute $i^{i^i}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find $i^{i^i}$ Show that it does not coincide with $i^{i\cdot i} =
> i^{−1}$

**Attempt:**
$$i^i = e^{i \log(i)} = e^{i[i(\pi/2 + 2n\pi)]} = e^{-\pi/2 - 2n\pi}$$

Thus,

$$i^{i^i}= e^{i^i \log (i)} = e^{ e^{-\pi/2 - 2n\pi}[i(\pi/2 + 2k\pi)]}$$

I am confused, does this have to be so much complicated? Also, how to show the second part exactly?

Comment: The second part is just raising both sides of

$$i^i = e^{- \pi / 2 - 2 n \pi}$$

to the power of $i$. I'm not sure what the difficulty is there. And yes, the only way I can think to make this "less complicated" (IMO it's simple as is) would be to let $n=k=0$ to limit considerations to the principal argument of the complex number.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer so the final answer that I wrote is correct ?

Comment: @$i^{i^i}$ means $i^{(i^i)}$, not $(i^i)^i$. In fact, $(i^i)^i=(e^{-\pi/2-2n\pi})^i$ can be unambiguously calculated as $e^{-i\pi/2-2in\pi}$, which is equal to $-i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt on the first part looks good to me. For the second part, by [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), if $a\ne0,1$ is an algebraic number and $b$ is not a *real* rational number, then $a^b$ is transcendental (regardless of the branch of logarithm one chooses when $a$ is complex). Apply the theorem with $a=b=i$, we see that $i^i$ is transcendental. Apply the theorem again with $a=i$ and $b=i^i$, we see that $i^{i^i}$ is transcendental. Hence it is not equal to $i^{-1}=-i$, which is algebraic.